# SQL - Group by group property?

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I've got a table of consignments (simplified of course)

```
CONSIGNMENT_NR    CUSTOMER
1                 1
2                 1
3                 2
4                 2
5                 2
```

I can easily select, for each customer, how many consignments they have:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM CONSIGNMENT
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```

Which will give me (with that example data):

```
CUSTOMER   Count
1          2
2          3
```

But what I want is to get how many customers made x amount of consignments.
The data I want would look like this:

```
Amount     No of Customers
2          1
3          1
```

I can't quite figure out how.

Comment: I don't understand how Amount:3 NoOfCustomers:1 row occurs? Your purpose is not clear to me

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Because there is one customer (customer 2) who made exactly 3 orders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your query up as a derived table. `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select Amount, count(*) as No_of_Customers
from
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Amount
    FROM CONSIGNMENT
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER
) dt
group by Amount
```

Comment: There we go! I actually tried the same, but did not include the "dt" bit. I'll look up what that is now (can only accept your answer 9 minutes from now).

Thanks!

Comment: The `dt` table alias shouldn't be needed, but some products still require it.

Comment: It gives me a bunch of syntax errors without it. Must be an MSSQL 2016 thing.

Answer (score 1):

you can try below - using subquery

```
select count(distinct customer) as noofcustomer, 'Count'
from
(
SELECT CUSTOMER, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM CONSIGNMENT
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
)A group by 'Count'
```